# What are entities in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, magento-2.0, eav, magento-2.0.4

Entities in Magento 2 are like:

- Product is an entity?
- Order/Sale is an entity?
- Customer/Users/Clients is an entity?
- etc??

**Where can I find a list of all entities?
Are they declarated in the DB?**

For example in `eav_attribute` table I can see a column `entity_type_id` that in a default Magento2 installation goes from 1 to 4, these number represents entities?

PD Taking in mind that `eav_entity` is empty in a default installation

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `eav_attribute` table's column `entity_type_id` is mapped to the `eav_entity_type` table, you can see the entities there.

[image]

Comment: FYI, order & related entities are not of EAV types.

Comment: @MagePsycho Thats very true, still they are present in the `eav_entity_type` table, but not sure why....

Comment: @AtishGoswami just curious, why **quote** is not part of this table.

Answer (score 5):

Well, englishly speaking, every object is an entity right ?

But I reckon you're referring to an entity as the `EAV` (Entity - Attribute - Value) implementation of Magento.

So to answer your question, I reckon you should have a look at the `eav_entity_type` table which lists the following entities with their entity model, table and attribute model:

- 1: Customer
- 2: Customer Address
- 3: Category
- 4: Product
- 5: Order
- 6: Invoice
- 7: Credit Memo
- 8: Shipment

Comment: I just notice that, ty for yor response

Comment: FYI, order & related entities are not of EAV types.

Comment: @MagePsycho yes I know, how funny is that that there are still referenced in this table.

Comment: Yeah it's all about legacy modes :)

Comment: hi @ Raphael at Digital Pianism, @MagePsycho is there any specifi entity type for product attributes or it is same entity as Catalog_product??I am not certain knowldge on

Answer (score 3):

I just notice it (and if it helps to someone)

The table `eav_entity_type` is where magento2 entities are, for example:

```
mysql> SELECT entity_type_id, entity_type_code FROM eav_entity_type;
+----------------+------------------+
| entity_type_id | entity_type_code |
+----------------+------------------+
|              3 | catalog_category |
|              4 | catalog_product  |
|              7 | creditmemo       |
|              1 | customer         |
|              2 | customer_address |
|              6 | invoice          |
|              5 | order            |
|              8 | shipment         |
+----------------+------------------+
8 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```