# What new tables need to be created when building module for custom attributes?

Tags: database, magento2.2, custom-attributes

**Magento 2.2** -- I am trying to build a module that would allow for custom attributes to be created in the admin panel.  At this point, I'm stuck on what tables need to be created to allow for that functionality.  Do I need to create one table that links to another?  That's what I've seen elsewhere in the core code...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Magento has different entities: product, customer, category etc. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/116504/43911

You don't need to create new tables for these entities to store values of attributes. Attributes can create from admin panel for a product or programmatically with installer [Magento 2 : Add Product Attribute Programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162113/magento-2-add-product-attribute-programmatically)

Also if you need to store any other values that don't relate to existing entities or configuration  of a module 
 ( [Magento 2 : Add Product Attribute Programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162113/magento-2-add-product-attribute-programmatically) )
then you need to have a separate new table https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-a-new-table-to-database/

Comment: Thanks!  That helped clarify my thoughts.  However, I'm not looking to just save attribute values, but actually create attributes in the admin panel (sorry if I misunderstood something in your answer...).  For example, I want to have a page in the admin panel that allows custom attributes to be created for a customers order.  Where would those custom attributes be saved?  Would I have to create a new table for that?

Comment: You need to create programmatically order attribute https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131969/43911

Comment: But how would creating a new column in that table help when saving a new, custom attribute in the admin panel?  I guess I'm not understanding how the custom attributes, created in the admin panel would get saved by doing that...

Comment: You can use this one example and update/save a value of attribute in the Observer
https://www.yereone.com/magento-2-how-to-add-new-order-attribute/